# Select global scope function at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11

I have to use third party SDK which does NOT provide any compile time information about its version.

Let's say v1 of SDK defines the following functions:

```
bool func1(int);
bool func2(float) {return false; /* not implemented */}
```

While v2 of the SDK deprecated and removed `func1()` and properly implemented `func2()`. I need to make my code to properly compile and work with both versions of SDK. If it's v1, then choose `func1`(), if not, then use `func2()`.

I've successfully implemented compile time inquiry whether global scope `func1()` exists:

```
constexpr bool hasFunc1();
```

I tried to select appropriate function using tag-dispatching and template specialization. For example:

```
template <bool THasFunc1>
struct ExecCode;

template<>
struct ExecCode<true>
{
    bool getValue() {
         return func1(123);
    }
}

template<>
struct ExecCode<false>
{
    bool getValue() {
         return func2(123.567);
    }
}

bool getValue() {
    return ExecCode<hasFunc1()>::getValue();
}
```

However, compiler (GCC) still reports an error `func1 has not been declared` when compiling with v2 of SDK. Why does it even try to compile the non-existing variant? Is there any way to allow the described selection of function from the **global** scope?

Comment: This might be better solved by using `#ifdef`, and *you* providing the correct version with `-D` command line switch. That's what macros are for.

Comment: If GCC points at the `ExecCode<true>` template specialization, it should have a `required from here:` line telling you why it thinks it needs that. Can you post the full error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be also solved without tag dispatching.

```
#include <iostream>

#if !defined(NEW_VERSION)
bool func1(int)   { std::cout << "Implemented" << std::endl;     return true;  }
bool func2(float) { std::cout << "Not implemented" << std::endl; return false; }
#else
bool func2(float) { std::cout << "Implemented" << std::endl;     return true;  }
#endif

namespace workaround {
struct null_type {};

template<typename T = null_type>
bool func1(int a, T t = T()) { return func2((float) a); }
}

void universal_implementation() {
    using namespace workaround;
    func1(123);
}

int main() { universal_implementation(); return 0; }
```

When `func1` is declared, `workaround::func1(int, workaround::null_type)` would have weaker priority than original function.

Comment: Your answer has guided me to a right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're running into a problem where you call a undeclared function with arguments not dependent on template parameters. That is deprecated, if still supported by GCC with permissive mode. Essentially compiler tried to add first implementation of `getValue()` to the template with parameter `"false"`. Possible workarounds are to use single template specification and `if constexpr` within `getValue()` or `#ifdef`.

Comment: I suppose you are right. However, I'm stuck with C++11 (not 14 or 17). Is there any way to make a compilation of my code SDK version agnostic without any additional defines and without patching of SDK headers? Can you think of a way to achieve what I need with just language features (such as templates)?