# How to detect if a enum is defined

Tags: c++, enums, metaprogramming, sfinae

Let's say I have the following code:

```cpp
// exposition-only, I can't use this macro in my solution
#if defined(HAS_MY_ENUM)
enum my_enum {
    zero,
    one,
};
#endif

enum empty {
    placeholder, // an enum must always have a value
};
```

I'd love to have a conditional type alias `my_enum_or_empty` that is set to `my_enum` if it is defined, otherwise it's set to `empty`, e.g.:

```cpp
using my_enum_or_empty = std::conditional<my_enum_exists, my_enum, empty>;
```

I want a SFINAE-based solution that gives me `my_enum_exists`.

I was thinking of [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45594334/1282773), but it requires a forward-declaration of `my_enum`, and it [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1280969/1282773) be forward declared, because it is sizeless. And I cannot add a size, because this `enum` comes from an external library. Do you have any ideas?

#### Restrictions

My use case is that this `my_enum` is defined in an external C library that I don't have control over. I need to compile my code against two versions of this library (with `my_enum` and without). The header sources, where `my_enum` is defined cannot be changed i.e. it *must* be an old C-style `enum`.

The library version is not known at compile time. Sadly, there is no `LIBRARY_VERSION` macro. I need to rely on this `enum` alone.

I cannot rely on the build system. In fact, I am doing a C++ *header-only* wrapper around this C code, hence there is no build system. Neither can I move responsibility to my customer. There are more than one type missing and there are many versions of this library, i.e. it'd be too complex for my wrapper user.

Comment: Why not continue to use `#if defined(HAS_MY_ENUM)` ... ?

Comment: @ivaigult what _do_ you have in the header to cause the conditional definition?

Comment: I have two versions of the _external_ library: old and new. One has the enum, one does not. My code should work for both versions.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? If you have a naming conflict use namespaces otherwise more information would be useful.

Comment: I cannot refactor the external C library to use namespaces, I'm afraid:)

Comment: I would love a way to handle this, but honestly I think you need some kind of version check on the library.

Comment: Is the library version known at compile time? Or do you need to do some sort of runtime magic?

Comment: What I usually do is create a C++ abstract baseclass with methods modeling what I would like to do in the 3rd party library. (with my own types etc). Then make an implementation using the 3rd party libary and inject the interface into the C++ code (dependency injection). That way I can also inject a mock for unit testing (a win-win in my book). The good thing is you can do the implementation in a static C++ library  which links the "C" library (thus hiding the "C" library as an implementation detail)

Comment: When compiling against old library `clang++ -DNO_MY_ENUM foo.cpp`, when compiling against new library `clang++ -DHAS_MY_ENUM foo.cpp`.

Comment: Your build system knows which library version it's building against at build time, right? Do what @Eljay said above. If the library doesn't expose a compile time definition, then define your own. `-DMY_LIBRARY_USING_THIRD_PARTY_LIBRARY_VERSION_ONE` etc

Comment: Also, I realize this is a stereotypical stackoverflow response, but: "Don't build against both 3PL versions. Just build against one."

Comment: So many questions here, thank you! I edited the notes section to better explain my use case.

Comment: If there's no build system (you're distributing this to customers), then move the build-system-compile-time-definition responsibility on to them.

"If you're using my wrapper, you MUST specific which version of 3PL you're building against. Do this by defining one of the following compile definitions..."

Comment: I get the desire to automate all of this away, but dependency management is HARD. Sometimes the best thing to do is tell customers that they have to do some extra leg work. For example, libcurl requires that any customers building against OpenSSL do extra work depending on the version of OpenSSL they are linking against. https://curl.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html

Comment: Best of luck. "I *need* a SFINAE solution" should be written "I *want* a SFINAE solution". If you figure it out, please add an answer here, because it's an interesting problem.

Comment: Related answer because it validates my point of view (therefore it is 100% correct and I will die on this hill) :P https://stackoverflow.com/a/53298232/2027196

Comment: For SFINAE to work the compiler still needs to know what it's dealing with. It's unsuitable for this kind of test. Many libs will define version macros though, which could be used to conditionally use different options. The only other option here would be to have your build system do a test compilation and decide based on the exit code of the compiler, which alternative should be used. One example is for this functionality is [cmake's `try_compile`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/try_compile.html)

Comment: Are there any other "proxy measurements" you can make about the 3PL at compile time to determine what version it is? Maybe there's a public struct that got a new member variable between versions A and B? Checking for the presence of a member variable is something you can do with SFINAE.

I'd expand this question to "how can I proxy-measure the version of a library?" for your own sanity.

Comment: This can't be done with SFINAE, because it can only be used to examine template parameters, and there's nothing about a global enum that can serve as one. [`requires` has the same issue.](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req.general#note-1) What is this library called and what enum are you checking for?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat with the practical question. Yeah this is beyond generalities. There might be a perfectly reasonable way to handle this given the specific library.

Comment: Also, contact the library maintainers and tell them to add a version macro to the next library iteration.

Comment: May be not exactly sfinae, I need something similar to [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48257767/select-global-scope-function-at-compile-time/48264444#48264444) with function fallback.

Comment: @ivaigult can you say what 3PL this is and which enum you're checking for?

Comment: Ok. Can you add the library name and the enum name?

Comment: Sorry, it's complicated: the headers are proprietary and licensed, so I cannot share:-( I can only says it describes some hardware. There is a library version, but changes between them are unmanageable. For my particular application, I need fallback types for ~100 types.

Comment: I see. You should probably mention it in the question. Also, use `@username` when replying to comments, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: Can I just say, your entire situation is a case of "been there, done that". When you say fallback types for ~100 types, there are still only 2 library versions right?

Comment: @ivaigult can you answer my question about whether there are any proxy measurements available? E.g., if there's a struct that has changed between versions, that's a gold mine for what you want.

Comment: @JanSchultke I don't think I can use `std::conditional<my_enum_exists, my_enum, empty>`, bc when `my_enum` is not defined, this will fail to compile. I think the semantic has to be `using my_enum_or_empy = ...`.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I understand it's is possible to use a solution that depends on the library version (or a structure's `sizeof`). The problem is that there are too many versions / types and that would be really hard to implement. Where as with with `my_${typename}_or_emtpy` semantics I could just list the super set of all types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this:

```cpp
template<typename T = int>
constexpr bool my_enum_exists = requires { my_enum(T{}); };
```

(Which can be implemented without the requires, you just need to SFINAE on the expression `my_enum(T{})`).

When `my_enum` *is* defined as a type, this will just check if you can do the functional cast `my_enum(0)`, which you can, so it passes.

When it's not defined, this will check if you can call a function called `my_enum` with `T{}` (via ADL, so you don't need a dummy function called `my_enum`), which will always fail for non-class type `int`.

---

Taking advantage of this "adl or type cast", you can make a struct that can find functions by ADL returning your empty type if the enum name can't be found. This can easily be expanded for multiple types:

```cpp
enum empty {
    placeholder, // an enum must always have a value
};
struct enum_existance_checker {
    // Convert to enum type or int argument type
    template<typename T> operator T();

    friend empty my_enum(int);
    friend empty my_other_enum(int);
    friend empty my_third_enum(int);
};

enum my_enum {};
// enum my_other_enum {};
enum my_third_enum {};

// This is a cast to my_enum, using the conversion operator.
using my_enum_or_empty = decltype(my_enum(enum_existance_checker{}));
static_assert(std::is_same_v<my_enum_or_empty, my_enum>);

// This is a call to the friend function, converting to int
using my_other_enum_or_empty = decltype(my_other_enum(enum_existance_checker{}));
static_assert(std::is_same_v<my_other_enum_or_empty, empty>);
```

Comment: Nice idea! What is the second set of `{ ... }` for?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat For me having `{ expr } -> type_constraint;` and just removing the `-> type_constraint` (Did not know you could remove those braces too!)

Answer (score 8):

@Artyer suggests a more practical approach [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76459918/2752075). I'm leaving this here mostly as a technical curiosity.

---

What you can do, if you know the name of the one of the constants in the enum, is to define it as a macro (assuming the target header doesn't use that name anywhere else), which would expand to itself plus some magic to detect whether it was used or not (stateful metaprogramming).

The following works with the assumption that the constant doesn't have a `= value` specified. If it does and you know the exact value beforehand, supporting that case should be trivial. If it does but you don't know the value, it might still be possible, but will be somewhat more ugly.

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace EnumDetector
{
    namespace detail
    {
        constexpr void _adl_EnumMarker() {} // Dummy ADL target.

        template <typename T>
        struct Reader
        {
            #if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
            #pragma GCC diagnostic push
            #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wnon-template-friend"
            #endif
            friend constexpr auto _adl_EnumMarker(Reader<T>);
            #if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
            #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
            #endif
        };

        template <typename T>
        struct Writer
        {
            friend constexpr auto _adl_EnumMarker(Reader<T>) {return true;}
        };

        template <typename T, typename = void> struct Value : std::false_type {};
        template <typename T> struct Value<T, std::enable_if_t<_adl_EnumMarker(Reader<T>{})>> : std::true_type {};
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline constexpr bool HaveEnum = detail::Value<T>::value;
}

#define ENUM_DETECTOR_REGISTER_WITHOUT_VALUE(tag_, enumerator_) \
    DETAIL_ENUM_DETECTOR_REGISTER_WITHOUT_VALUE(__COUNTER__, tag_, enumerator_)

#define DETAIL_ENUM_DETECTOR_REGISTER_WITHOUT_VALUE(counter_, tag_, enumerator_) \
    DETAIL_ENUM_DETECTOR_CAT(_enum_detector_helper_,counter_), \
    DETAIL_ENUM_DETECTOR_CAT(_enum_detector_helper2_,counter_) = (void(::EnumDetector::detail::Writer<tag_>{}), 0), \
    enumerator_ = DETAIL_ENUM_DETECTOR_CAT(_enum_detector_helper_,counter_)

#define DETAIL_ENUM_DETECTOR_CAT(x, y) DETAIL_ENUM_DETECTOR_CAT_(x, y)
#define DETAIL_ENUM_DETECTOR_CAT_(x, y) x##y

// ---
// Repeat following for all enums:

struct MyEnumTag {};

#define my_enum_constant ENUM_DETECTOR_REGISTER_WITHOUT_VALUE(MyEnumTag, my_enum_constant)

// ---

#ifdef YOUR_LIB_INCLUDE_GUARD // <-- Customize this for the target library, or remove altogether if it uses `#pragma once`.
#error "Must not include this stuff elsewhere.."
#endif

// #include <stuff.h>
enum SomeEnum { x, y, my_enum_constant, z, w }; // Try commenting me out to trigger the assertion.

// ---
// Repeat following for all enums:

#undef my_enum_constant

// ---
// Lastly, the usage:
static_assert(EnumDetector::HaveEnum<MyEnumTag>);
```